# Unable to set firefox bookmark description for in Add-On Kit API

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I found the `nsINavBookmarksService`, however since Firefox 3, it does not seem to have any API methods for getting/setting the Bookmark description. [(API doc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsINavBookmarksService#createFolder%28%29)

I've seen other Add-Ons modify the description as a method of synchronized data storage (which is exactly what I'm trying to do).  I'm guessing perhaps the description is a non-gecko standard, and that's why it is not directly supported, but then there must be a completely different interface for manipulating Bookmarks that I haven't discovered.

Can anyone help with this newbie problem?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Firefox 3 the bookmarks have been merged into the Places database containing all of your browsing history. So to get the bookmarks you do a history query, like this (first line is [specific to the Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html) which you appear to be using):

```js
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var historyService = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-history-service;1"]
                       .getService(Ci.nsINavHistoryService);
var options = historyService.getNewQueryOptions();
var query = historyService.getNewQuery();
query.onlyBookmarked = true;

var result = historyService.executeQuery(query, options);
result.root.containerOpen = true;
for (var i = 0; i < result.root.childCount; i++)
{
  var node = result.root.getChild(i);
  console.log(node.title);
}
```

That's mostly identical to the code example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Retrieving_part_of_the_bookmarks_tree). Your problem is of course that [nsINavHistoryResultNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsINavHistoryResultNode) has no way of storing data like a description. You can set annotations however, see [Using the Places annotation service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Places_annotation_service). So if you already have a `node` variable for your bookmark:

```js
var annotationName = "my.extension.example.com/bookmarkDescription";
var ioService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                  .getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
var uri = ioService.newURI(node.uri, null, null);
var annotationService = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/annotation-service;1"]
                          .getService(Ci.nsIAnnotationService);
annotationService.setPageAnnotation(uri, annotationName,
     "Some description", 0, Ci.nsIAnnotationService.EXPIRE_NEVER);
```

For reference: [nsIAnnotationService.setPageAnnotation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIAnnotationService#setPageAnnotation%28%29)

Comment: But wait, wait. Ok, for the question the answer is annotations, but what if I really want to get/set the description of something in the bookmarks?

Comment: @pihentagy: You set the `"bookmarkProperties/description"` annotation, that's apparently the one used by Places internally.